# Google Play - Android .aab package contains huge size artefacts in a build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play, build.gradle, android-app-bundle

When I try to a new build release/debug version of my app via Build -> Generate Signed Bundle/APK, the result package is badly inflated in size with unknown content. Increased size is x10 (from 5 to 51 mb).

Using Android Studio: Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1, also tried the latest stable Dolphin version.

When I compare builds I can see new artefacts like "base/root/native/mac" which is like extra XXmb.

please refer to the screenshot below:

[image]

[image]

What is this /native thing and how to get rid of it?

This is how Google Play breaks down the bundle content. Here is is marked as "Other".

[image]

In this new version of the app my only changes are:

1. targetSDKversion build 32-> 33
2. version updates of some dependencies like Android Auto, Firebase, Billing, android core
3. Few changes in business logic
4. NO new drawables or any other resources

Comment: could you please expand and show the content of the following folders: aarch64 and x86_64? thanks

Comment: Hi @Lino let me attach it to the original post. There are some lib files, but i cannot find any info about the nature of those libs online.

Comment: it seems something related to [robolectric](https://robolectric.org). Did you check if this library has been included with `testImplementation` in the build.gradle file?

Comment: @Lino it's quite small project, where i'm the only dev and i do just my own testing, so my only testImplementation dependencies are this ones: **    //Test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'


    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"  **

Answer (score 0):

The reason was in this dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.car.app:app-testing:1.3.0-rc01'
```

it bring unnecessary components to the build.
to avoid the issue use instead:

```
implementation "androidx.car.app:app:1.3.0-alpha01"
```